# Two antiderivatives for just one integral

Tags: calculus

I have recently been learning integrals and the substitution rule. Whilst doing some exercises, I came up to this:

$$\int\csc^2(2\theta)\cot(2\theta)d\theta$$

I had to integrate using the substitution law using a) $u = \cot(2\theta)$, and,
b) $u = \csc(2\theta)$

I did both ways and to my surprise I got different results and after checking the answers I found out both were right! But why? Could an integral have two general antiderivatives?

The answers I've reached were $-(1/4) \cot^2(2\theta) + C$ and $-(1/4) \csc^2(2\theta) + C$

Comment: This is the exact reason for the +C on indefinite integration

Comment: It is because $1 + \cot^2(x) = \csc^2(x)$:

Welcome to the land of [trig identitiies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities